# Find an example given Hypotheses , DCT does not hold

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose the below are true :

**(1)** 
Functions:

$f_n \to f$ a.e , whic means $f_n$ converges almost everywhere to function $f$ , also
              $g_n \to g$  a.e
              $h_n \to h$  a.e

**2)** 
  $g_n$ , $h_n$ and $f_n$ are integrable for all $n \ge 1$

$g$ , $h$ and $f$ are integrable , also

$\int  g_n dμ  \to \int  g dμ$ **,**
$\int  f_n dμ  \to \int  f dμ$ **,**
$\int  h_n dμ  \to \int  h dμ$

**3)** $g_n \le f_n \le h_n$ a.e

Given the above **1, 2, 3** Hypotheses are true .

How can we **find an example** where the Hypotheses Dominated Convergence Theorem **Fails to hold**

Could you please also prove to me and explain why the specific example works?

Comment: You can simplify this  a lot by taking $f_n=g_n=h_n$. I don't see the point in taking three sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f_n=g_n=h_n=nE_{[2^n,2^n+\frac{1}{n^2}]}(x)$, where $E_{\circ}$ is the characteristic function, then you see that $f_n,g_n,h_n$ converge to $0$ a.e., all your hypotheses (1), (2), (3) are satisfied, but there exists no dominating integrable bound $h$ for all $f_n$, since otherwise we must have
$$h\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty n E_{[2^n,2^n+\frac{1}{n^2}]}$$
and the integral of the r.h.s. is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty$. Thus the Lebesgue DCT is not applicable.

Comment: I am not relevant to the charachteristic function idea , $E_{[2^n,2^n+\frac{1}{n^2}]}(x) $. Is there any alternative way to write this? thank you

Comment: This is also called the indicator function, see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: So we can write it as follows ? we have measure space $( \Bbb{R} , \mathcal{R} , λ)$ and $h_n(ω)= n I_{[2^n,2^n+\frac{1}{n^2}]} $ Then $ 0  \leq h_n(ω)=n I_{[2^n,2^n+\frac{1}{n^2}]}  (ω) \to 0  for all ω \in \Bbb{R}. $  and $ h \geq $  $\int h_n dλ = \int \sum_{n=1}^\infty n I_{[2^n,2^n+\frac{1}{n^2}]} dλ$  ??

Comment: Could you please let tell me how do we know that $h\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty n I_{[2^n,2^n+\frac{1}{n^2}]}$ ?

Comment: This is because all the $f_n$'s have disjoint supports, so at each of the support, $h$ is  $\geq$ each $f_n$. maybe you can try to draw a picture in the plane to see this.